# matlab optimization: objective function with dependent decision variable

Tags: matlab, optimization, objective-function

I want to optimize an objective function with dependent decision variables as below.

```
Sum [I * (x(i) - x(i-1) + lo(i) - g(i)) * p(i)]
```

Please note that the decision variable is only x(i) and x(i-1) is a value came from previous step of optimization.
I have no idea how to write this objective function. Should I use function handler? Thanks

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. What do you mean, "previous step of optimization?"

Comment: I mean by  "previous step of optimization" is x(i-1). Can I use diff(x) for that?

Comment: By "previous step of optimization" do you mean you're trying to optimization some function using an iterative method? (i.e. compute some x_1 in step 1, then computes some x_2 in step 2 etc...)

If so, your question is completely screwy because the objective function of a well defined optimization problem will in NO WAY refer to the method used to solve it. If I'm trying to `minimize f(x)`, I could solve it by hand, I could solve it using numerical methods on a computer etc...; `f` shouldn't refer to what method I'm using to try to solve it. So I'm confused what you're trying to do or ask.

Comment: Ok, let me paraphrase the question. Can I write that objective function using vectorization method for the optimization?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're asking?

Imagine you have a 3 by 1 vector x.

```
       [x_1
  x =   x_2
        x_3]
```

and you want to compute:

```
      [x_1         [0
  y=   x_2    -     x_1
       x_3          x_2]
```

You could do this in Matlab with the code:

```
y = x - [0;x(1:end-1)];
```

this works since x(1:end-1) will refer to `[x_1; x_2]`. You can use this snippet to write your overall objective function.